# Compatibility level when upgrading a SQL Server 2005 database to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssms, upgrade, compatibility-level

I would like to move my databases which are currently running on SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012, using the Copy Database Wizard in SQL Server Management Studio.

Should I *first* set the database compatibility level to SQL Server 2012 (while the database still exists on SQL Server 2005) or should I set the compatibility level to SQL Server 2005 after I've moved the database?

Comment: Compatibility level is only for T-SQL, you don't need to for the upgrade. Make sure you have a backup :) in case something goes wrong in your inline upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

You can not set the compatibility level of a SQL Server 2005 instance to anything higher.
Hence the upgrade path:

Create SQL Server 2012 Server / Instance.

- Option 1: Backup / Restore; change compatibility level.
- Option 2: Detach, copy, Attach; change compatibility level.

Option 1 is most used because you have overlap (old is available, new can be tested).
Rollback to previous is certain.

Misread your question. You want to remain at SQL 2005 compatibility: Don't change compatibility level during option 1 or 2. Compatibility is configured at the database level.

Comment: I really try to discourage detach/attach. Just dangerous. If you care about your data, you're already taking backups, so you already have a backup to restore. If you detach your database because you don't have backups, and then something happens to the file, you now have ZERO copies of your database.